# Device Type identification from MAC address

Tags: iphone, android, mac-address

Can I determine if a device is IPhone/IPad/IPod or Android from its MAC address ? MAC addresses can be used to identify the manufacturer but can I distinguish a Macbook pro from an IPhone ?

Answer (score 1):

Unless Apple uses unique wifi chipset suppliers for a Macbook that would never be used for an iphone (e.g. samsung for iphone and toshiba for macbook), a mac address will only ever tell you who manufactured the particular wifi chip in use. Maybe certain ranges of mac addresses would only ever show up in one type of device, but you'd have to compile that list yourself.

Comment: It is even possible that a vendor uses 2 different vendor ID's in the mac-addresses of the same chip (different minor revisions, produced in different factories, etc.). Intel, Atheros, Realtek, Broadcom and 3Com have all done this several times. In some cases you can't even tell if it's a wired or wifi chip (e.g. Atheros used the same vendor id for 1Gb/s wired and 802.11n wifi nic's. There are probably more examples of this.)

Comment: Yep. only the first 16bits of the mac address are specific. The other 32bits can be anything the vendor wants.